# Is there an app that allows me to remotely access and play my hard drive's music files?

Tags: remote-access

Is there an program that allows me to remotely access and play my hard drive's music files?

I found and downloaded a program called 'sockso' that would have worked, if it was still supported, at least it would have allowed me to access and play music off of my hard drive through an open port.

I simply want to set up a program on my laptop (accessible via wifi) and access it from my phone or tablet.

I desire an program that remotely either plays my hard drive resident songs randomly or allows me to set up a play list.

There are probably a million ways to do similar things using other techniques, but:

1. I want the files to be physically on my laptop's hard drive and
2. Accessible remotely (a resident program running on the laptop is OK).

Answer (score 4):

Some apps that shows up in quick search on Play Store:

- [Samba Network Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.threecats.sambaplayer) -- runs using Samba sharing and folder (having music) should be shared (via Properties).

  > Listen to your network stored music collection as if it was all on your phone!
  >
  > Enjoy music right away, no complicated setup required. Samba Player works with shared folders from Windows, Linux, Mac, home routers, media players, network drives (NAS) or any network device that can share folders.
  >
  > - works over WiFi, Ethernet or even in Hotspot mode.
  > - music formats: MP3, MP4 audio (m4a), Ogg Vorbis (ogg) and FLAC (on Android 3.1+)
  > - indexes your music collection for fast browsing without the lag of the network.
  > - smart streaming lets you enjoy your music better on slow networks
  > - download the playlist with one click and listen to it on the go!
  > - edit, shuffle and repeat your playlist
- [Soumi: Network Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.techsoftpl.musicplayer) -- You need to run a server like [FTP](https://serverfault.com/questions/85027/how-do-i-setup-an-ftp-server-on-windows-7)/[SSH](https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows)/[WebDAV](https://superuser.com/questions/410278/how-to-set-up-a-local-webdav-server-for-use-with-goodreader-on-the-ipad), or just share a folder and allow sharing through network settings in Windows.

  > Scan, catalogue, and play music files alike from internal/external SD card, shared folders on local network, FTP/FTPS, SFTP, WebDAV servers, Dropbox, Google Drive, and other cloud services that support WebDAV protocol like BOX, CloudMe, ownCloud, etc., through WiFi or mobile network. It has easy intuitive user interface for instant searching and browsing music by artist, album, genre, as well as folder.
  >
  > It can also cache music files from the network folder when added to a playlist so that you can play them later when not connected to any WiFi or mobile network.  It uses SAMBA/CIFS protocol to access the network shard folder, i.e., no uPnp or DLNA server is required.
  >   Key features are:
  >
  > - Plays music from shared folders on local SMB/CIFS network, e.g., Windows share, WiFi drive, NAS, USB drive attached to router, etc.
  > - Plays music from FTP, FTPS, SFTP, and WebDAV servers
  > - Plays music from Dropbox, Google Drive, and other WebDAV based cloud services like BOX, CloudMe, ownCloud, etc.
  > - Play music from internal/external SdCard and attached USB drives
  > - Supports multitasking, e.g., it can play music, cache playlist from network, scan folders, etc., all at the same time
  > - Browsing and instant searching by artist, album, genre, and title
  > - Find, browse and play music by folder
  > - Instant sorting by title, album, artist, genre, year, album count, song count, time added, play time, etc.

---

<sup>Finding answers for this question is  trivial. There are so many apps available on web and waiting for one query from Google like "how to stream music from PC to Android" or "network stream music from PC to Android", etc. Have fun diving in plethora of apps. :-)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Plex](https://plex.tv/) or [Emby](http://emby.media/) (formerly Media Browser). Both of them do this. 
You'll need to install and set them up on on your PC and install them on your phone/tablet, too.